# How was the tabernacle kept cool?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle

It seems with so many layers of thick cover the tabernacle would be well over 120 degrees at times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Chabad.org

> The clouds that surrounded the camp fulfilled a four-fold purpose:
>
> 1. to protect the people from the searing desert sun; (Shulchan Aruch Harav, Orach Chaim, ch. 625, Isaiah 4:6. See also Psalms 105:39)

This would possibly explain why the sun wasn't heating it up, but not the heat from the fire on the altar.

Comment: About the altar, bear in mind that the one with the "constant fire" was outdoors and open to the air (so the heat would dissipate). The Golden Altar had fire on it only twice a day, while the incense was burning, and that didn't necessarily take that long.